# Is there an equivalent to `run_at: start` in a background page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to run some JavaScript code before any other code is executed on the page that's being loaded.

That works fine using a content script like this:

```
{
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*"],
  "js": ["contentScript.js"],
  "run_at": "document_start"
}
```

But now I'd like to run the content script only on certain pages which the user selects by clicking on the browser action button.

I've tried listening to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` and then calling `executeScript`, but other code is running on the page before my content script.

Is there a way to ensure that the code injected by a background page is run before other code?

I could also add a condition inside my content script, but that would mean I need access to the current tabId and a list of all tabs where my extension is activated.

Comment: [`runAt: "document_start"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

Comment: @wOxxOm Nice, didn't see that. Works well for me. Happy to accept as answer if you post one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) has several useful parameters, including `runAt` (by default it's `document_idle`, which occurs after DOMContentLoaded event), so to inject a script as soon as possible use `runAt: 'document_start'`.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
    runAt: 'document_start',
    code: 'console.log(document.documentElement.innerHTML);',
});
```

Beware the DOM tree is usually empty at this stage especially if you inject from an early executed event listener such as tabs.onUpdated or webNavigation.onCommitted. Even HEAD or BODY elements may be still absent, so you'd have to use `(document.head || document.documentElement)` fallback as a container for any added nodes such as `<style>` or `<script>`.

Comment: Note: The actual performance of using `runAt:'document_start'` compared to the *manifest.json* `"run_at": "document_start"` will depend greatly on when, *exactly*, you execute the `tabs.executeScript()` in relationship to the process of loading the page. Effectively, using `runAt:'document_start'` really means that the injection of the script is not purposefully delayed beyond when the `tabs.executeScript()` runs. It does *not* guarantee that the script is injected prior to the page being loaded (i.e. with `head` and `body` being `null`, as is guaranteed using the *manifest.json* option).